# Clearing session on one page

Tags: http, jsp

I have two pages, and both repopulate the fields of the page with what the user enters as the user navigates back and forth from the pages.

Is there any way to clear the field of just one page.

I was looking at the .invalidate method...

Comment: im using sessions by the way...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Can't you just not repopulate the page that you want to clear?

Comment: Some codes will be helpful. If you just want clear one value try remove.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#removeAttribute%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

`.Invalidate()` method should do it.